# Is it possible to install specific version of Python more than once on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation, registry, pyside

I'd like to know if installing specific version of Python more than once on Windows is possible.
I'm asking about normal installation procedure leading to full Python environment so *virtualenv* is not an option here.
I'm concerned for example with registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Python/PythonCore/<Version>` which may be used during installation of other libraries/programs to find out Python's installation folder.

Background:
I'd like to test difference between installing *PySide* normally and from within *virtualenv*. I don't want to use my working Python installation for this so I need clean Python installation for duration of my test to coexist side by side with existing one.

Comment: Use a virtual machine such as virtualbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use multiple registry files (*.reg) to switch between multiple Python interpreters of the same version but installed in different locations. Adjust version number and location in this template:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y\Help]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y\Help\Main Python Documentation]
@="C:\\PythonXY\\Doc\\pythonXYZ.chm"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y\InstallPath]
@="C:\\PythonXY\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y\InstallPath\InstallGroup]
@="Python X.Y"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y\Modules]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\X.Y\PythonPath]
@="C:\\PythonXY\\Lib;C:\\PythonXY\\DLLs"
```

Comment: Is there any official document describing what registry keys does Python installation use?

Comment: The PythonPath entry is explained at http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#finding-modules.

InstallPath is used by bdist_* installers (e.g. http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/PC/bdist_wininst/install.c?view=markup) and other software (e.g. CMake) to locate Python installation locations.

Answer (score -1):

You can install several Python versions on Windows; I did this and did not notice any adverse effects.

When you install a package, you just run the version of interpreter to which you want to install the package, that is, `python31 setup.py install` or such. The interpreter knows where its home is.

Also, consider using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) if you have to handle multiple Python or packages versions. This way you'll have as many different 'installations' of Python and/or packages as you want, without touching system-wide stuff.